# Authenticating to Azure Key Vault locally using DefaultAzureCredential

Tags: python, azure, azure-keyvault, azure-sdk-python

I am attempting to run this ['Retrieve a secret from the vault'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/python/api/overview/azure/key-vault?view=azure-python#examples) example locally (Ubuntu 19.10) to retrieve a secret from an Azure Key Vault:

```
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

client = SecretClient(vault_url="https://<<vaultname>>.vault.azure.com",
                      credential=DefaultAzureCredential())

secret = client.get_secret("<<mysecret>>")
```

However I receive the following error:

> azure.core.exceptions.ClientAuthenticationError:
>
> No credential in this chain provided a token.
>
> Attempted credentials:
>
> EnvironmentCredential: Incomplete environment configuration. See https://aka.ms/python-sdk-identity#environment-variables for
>   expected environment variables
>
> ImdsCredential: IMDS endpoint unavailable
>
> Please visit the documentation at
>
> https://aka.ms/python-sdk-identity#defaultazurecredential
>
> to learn what options DefaultAzureCredential supports

The [documentation on Service-to-Service authentication to Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication#authenticating-with-azure-cli) seems to suggest that I should be able to authenticate by the Azure CLI, and I've followed the steps to login via `az login`, select the appropriate subscription (which I've done just in case, despite only having one), and verify access via `az account get-access-token --resource https://vault.azure.net` which does return a token, however still receive the error above.

Am I wrong in assuming I should be able to authenticate after logging in via the cli?

And if so, and I need to manually set the environment variables described in the documentation link provided for `EnvironmentCredential`, what values do I need to supply for `AZURE_CLIENT_ID` and `AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I wrong in assuming I should be able to authenticate after logging in via the cli?

You're not wrong, it's possible with the current preview version of `azure-identity`, 1.4.0b2 as I write this. With that installed, your code should work once you've logged in to the CLI.

> ... what values do I need to supply for `AZURE_CLIENT_ID` and `AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET`?

These would be the client (or "application") ID of a service principal, and one of its secrets. The [azure-keyvault-secrets documentation](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-keyvault-secrets/4.1.0/index.html#create-a-service-principal-optional) describes how to create a service principal and configure its access to a Key Vault, using the CLI.

Briefly restating that documentation here, you can create a service principal with this command:

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac --name http://my-application
```

From the output of that command, "appId" is the value of `AZURE_CLIENT_ID` and "password" is the value of `AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET`.

Then, to grant the service principal access to the Key Vault's secrets:

```
az keyvault set-policy --name <<vaultname>> --spn $AZURE_CLIENT_ID --secret-permissions get set list delete backup recover restore purge
```