# Can't authenticate to KeyVault - No credential in this chain provided a token

Tags: azure-sdk-python

I'm trying to authenticate to a Key Vault using `DefaultAzureCredential` object with username/password authentication, but I'm getting this error:

```
[06/10/2020 13:57:37] Exception: ClientAuthenticationError: 
[06/10/2020 13:57:37] No credential in this chain provided a token.
[06/10/2020 13:57:37] Attempted credentials:
[06/10/2020 13:57:37]   EnvironmentCredential: Authentication failed: Unable to find wstrust endpoint from MEX. This typically happens when attempting MSA accounts. More details available here. https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/wiki/Username-Password-Authentication
[06/10/2020 13:57:37] 
[06/10/2020 13:57:37] Please visit the documentation at
[06/10/2020 13:57:37] https://aka.ms/python-sdk-identity#defaultazurecredential
[06/10/2020 13:57:37] to learn what options DefaultAzureCredential supports
```

I can confirm that the required environment variables are being loaded from `local.settings.json`:

- `AZURE_CLIENT_ID`
- `AZURE_USERNAME`
- `AZURE_PASSWORD`

Relevant code:

```py
def encrypt(text):
    uri = os.environ['KEYVAULT_URI']
    credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
    key_client = KeyClient(vault_url=uri, credential=credential)

    key = key_client.get_key("managed-key")
    crypto_client = CryptographyClient(key, credential=credential)
    plaintext = text.encode()

    return crypto_client.encrypt(EncryptionAlgorithm.rsa_oaep, plaintext)
```

`local.settings.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "{AzureWebJobsStorage}",
    "KEYVAULT_URI": "<keyvault_uri>",
    "AZURE_CLIENT_ID": "<client_id>",
    "AZURE_USERNAME": "<email>",
    "AZURE_PASSWORD": "<password>"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Authenticating to Azure Key Vault locally using DefaultAzureCredential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61125219/authenticating-to-azure-key-vault-locally-using-defaultazurecredential)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing the question I read the docs and found out the reason. Also the error trace is clear:

```
This typically happens when attempting MSA accounts.
```

Can't use a personal Microsoft account for this. Only work and school accounts would do.

From [Username Password Authentication](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/wiki/Username-Password-Authentication):

> By design and policy, the username/password authentication works only
>   for Work and school accounts, **but not for Microsoft Accounts (MSA)**.

I switched to **service principal with secret** and it solved my problem.

Details on options available at [EnvironmentCredential](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-identity/1.2.0/azure.identity.html#azure.identity.EnvironmentCredential).

```
"AZURE_TENANT_ID": "",
"AZURE_CLIENT_ID": "",
"AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET": ""
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that upgrading my python package resolved this issue for me.

```
pip install --upgrade azure-identity
```

I had 1.2.0, and upgraded to 1.4.0.

Comment: The [documentation](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/wiki/Username-Password-Authentication#constraints) still has the constraint for MSA accounts. Should the docs be updated as well? Otherwise this shouldn`t work.